# Why is "url_for" undefined in my application?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm trying to use the url_for extension so my app can accurately find my static assets (tried the static assets extension as well, but it also complained of this same problem).

The problem is this:

```
undefined method `url_for' for Sinatra::Raffler:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Now, I've got the required modules listed, as per the url_for README:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'data_mapper'
require 'lib/authorization'
require 'pony'
gem 'emk-sinatra-url-for'
require 'sinatra/url_for'
```

But I'm still getting the NoMethodError when I try to call url_for

I have tried a couple of different things in regards to helpers. First, I have a helpers block for an authorization extension:

```
helpers do
    include Sinatra::Authorization
end
```

So, I thought I could include the url_for helper in there:

```
helpers do
    include Sinatra::Authorization
    include Sinatra::UrlForHelper
end
```

But that didn't resolve the issue, so I just added the line:

```
 helpers Sinatra::UrlForHelper
```

after that initial helpers do block, but still no resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are subclassing Sinatra::Base, you need to include the helpers explicitly:

```
class Foobar < Sinatra::Base
  helpers Sinatra::UrlForHelper
end
```

Comment: I tried a couple of things in reference to including the helpers explicitly. Still no dice. (See edit above for details). Thanks for your thoughts!

Comment: I don't know how I managed to get it to work, but I did, and I'm using the line you showed me, so you get the answer. ;)  I'm still stuck on trying to get to my static assets, but I'll post another question in regards to that. Thanks again!